# Oracle Instant Client Basic or Basic Lite

Tags: oracle

I downloaded instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip from Oracle site, but in the installation step they mentioned **"All installations require the Basic or Basic Lite package."**.

Can you send me the exact link and steps to install that Basic or Basic Lite.

Also i after extracting that zip file, there is no such Setup.exe file, i am seeing only these 3 exe files. adrci.exe, genezi.exe, uidrvci.exe.

whether this is the exact .exe files or something else and for what purpose these .exe files are.

Thanks and Regards,
Ramachandran.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/ic-faq-094177.html

Answer (score 2):

With Oracle Instant Client, there is no `setup.exe`, no `install.exe`, no `install.sh`, ... no installer whatsoever. It is a mere unzip -> configure what's necessary -> point your Oracle client apps to it -> use it.

As soon as you have extracted the contents of the ZIP file, your Instant Client **is** "installed".

**Edit:** Since this software does not get *installed*, you won't see it in the list of the installed software in your Windows.

Comment: So can't i see that Oracle Client is installed on my machine like other softwares we will see in "All Programs".